# Optimize script for huge concatenated files / loop to discard defective items from list of files

Tags: python, split, python-itertools

EDIT: replaced the example file with a real example; replaced the `nbratoms` variable by `nbrbonds`.

Beginner question.

I would like to optimize the following script for huge files (100G+). I've discovered the existence of itertools yesterday but don't have a clue.

```
f = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
out = open(sys.argv[2], 'w')

lines = f.read().split('\n@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE')

for i in lines: 
    ii=i.split('\n@<TRIPOS>',4) 
    header=ii[0]
    infos=header.split('\n')[2]
    nbrbonds=infos.split(' ')[2]
    if str(nbrbonds) in ii[2]:
        out.write('\n@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE'+str(i))

out.close()
f.close()
```

The processed file is composed of concatenated 200,000+ single MOL2 files (last example below).
The idea of the script is to first split the input file into items delimited by  two `@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE` (=first line of a new MOL2 file); then to split these items according to lines starting with `@<TRIPOS>` into 4 parts (i.e.,`@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE`, `@<TRIPOS>ATOM`, `@<TRIPOS>BOND` and `@<TRIPOS>ALT_TYPE`). For each single MOL2 file, I want to check if the value at the location of (the second)`14` in the header (different in each single MOL2 file)

```
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
Z1198223644
14 14 0 0 0
USER_CHARGES
```

occurs in the 3rd part (below) of the single file:

```
@<TRIPOS>BOND
1       1       2 1
2       2       3 1
3       2       4 1
4       2       5 1
5       5       6 ar
6       5      11 ar
 ...
```

If it does -> print it to outputfile with `\n@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE` as first line (essentially just the way a single MOL2 file looks).
It seems to work as it is, but I fear it's way too amateur. Additionally, I don't know how to implement a step that would avoid that the output file starts with a double header mark like this

```
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
Z1198223644
...
```

Any help welcome! I joined a [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5hvp8w39f2m004u/test4?dl=0) containing 6 concatenated MOL2 files; odd files are correct; even files - wrong.

```
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
Z1198223644
14 14 0 0 0
USER_CHARGES
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
  1 F1         23.5932    2.0831  -52.2012 F      1 LIG      -0.15900
  2 C2         22.4195    1.3866  -52.4217 C.3    1 LIG       0.88300
  3 F3         22.5324    0.1265  -51.8643 F      1 LIG      -0.15900
  4 F4         21.3805    2.0570  -51.7993 F      1 LIG      -0.15900
  5 C5         22.1912    1.2555  -53.9016 C.ar   1 LIG       0.04500
  6 C6         21.0466    1.7681  -54.5284 C.ar   1 LIG      -0.13400
  7 C7         20.8964    1.6126  -55.9046 C.ar   1 LIG      -0.19400
  8 C8         21.8881    0.9505  -56.6271 C.ar   1 LIG       0.20700
  9 O9         21.7710    0.7997  -57.8724 O.2    1 LIG      -0.49500
 10 N10        22.9825    0.4691  -55.9778 N.ar   1 LIG       0.11300
 11 N11        23.1254    0.6186  -54.6592 N.ar   1 LIG      -0.68800
 12 H12        20.2773    2.2819  -53.9665 H      1 LIG       0.21400
 13 H13        20.0176    2.0033  -56.4027 H      1 LIG       0.20000
 14 H14        23.7285   -0.0277  -56.5143 H      1 LIG       0.32600
@<TRIPOS>BOND
  1       1       2 1
  2       2       3 1
  3       2       4 1
  4       2       5 1
  5       5       6 ar
  6       5      11 ar
  7       6       7 ar
  8       7       8 ar
  9       8       9 2
 10       8      10 ar
 11      10      11 ar
 12       6      12 1
 13       7      13 1
 14      10      14 1
@<TRIPOS>ALT_TYPE
CGenFF_4.0_ALT_TYPE_SET
CGenFF_4.0 1 FGA3 2 CG302 3 FGA3 4 FGA3 5 CG2R62 6 CG2R62 7 CG2R62 8 CG2R63 9 OG2D4 10 NG2R61 11 NG2R62 12 HGR62 13 HGR62 14 HGP1
```

Comment: i don't think itertools would be of much help as your bottleneck lies surely in the i/o. for the amateur part, your test `if str(nbratoms) in ii[2]:` looks weak. unless you're sure there never will be any conflict between nbratoms and the BOND columns (the third column looks dangerous) you'd better check the number of lines in BOND

Comment: @bobrobbob Thank you for your input! I replaced the example file with a real example; in the BOND columns there cannot be more bonds than the max number of bonds specified in the header.

Comment: if you say it's ok, then my bad. back to your optimization i think what you need is memory mapping but i barely know what it is, so i can't help you

Comment: @bobrobbob easy :-) I'm here to learn! I'll look into it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for memory efficient reading of file lines (i.e. split by `\n` or OS-specific line endings) you could have used:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f, open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as out:
    for i in f:
        ...
```

but you need to split by `'\n@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE'`, so I recommend to create your own generator (a function with `yield`) to produce MOLECULE chunks, loading only 1 chunk into memory (lazy reading the large file, instead of using the greedy `read()`):

```
def mol_reader(file_stream):
    chunk = []
    for line in file_stream:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == "@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE":
            if chunk:
                yield chunk
            chunk = []
        else:
            chunk.append(line)
    yield chunk


with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f, open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as out:
    for mol_file in mol_reader(f):
        ...
```

e.g. https://repl.it/@PeterAprillion/chunk-iterator

Comment: Thanks you very much for the time you invested!
Short question: is there any way to get a chunk not in the form of a list but of an entire string?

Comment: e.g. `yield '\n'.join(chunk)`

Comment: Sorry for the delay : Thank you very very very much! I managed to implement it just perfect! master's thesis saved!